# dhcpcd: Can't assign IP

Tags: dhcp

I have recently changed my network configuration. One of the things I changed was the DHCP server, which was previously in the router.

I am seeing the following messages in `daemon.log`:

```
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: rebinding lease of 10.0.1.179
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: NAK: Can't assign IP from 10.0.1.50
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: message: Can't assign IP
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: offered 10.0.1.179 from 10.0.1.48
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: NAK: Can't assign IP from 10.0.1.50
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: message: Can't assign IP
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: offered 10.0.1.179 from 10.0.1.48
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: NAK: Can't assign IP from 10.0.1.50
Jan 25 15:21:11 octopi dhcpcd[1025]: eth0: message: Can't assign IP
```

The last 4 messages repeat several times. 10.0.1.50 is the old DHCP server, 10.0.1.48 is the new one. I eventually get `eth0: leased 10.0.1.179 for 43200 seconds`, but it takes longer than it should to actually get an IP address.

I've tried manually releasing the eth0 lease via `dhcpcd -k eth0` and restarting dhcpcd (and even rebooting). I've also tried doing `systemctl stop dhcpcd; rm /var/lib/dhcpcd5/*` and rebooting, and still the same.

From the error message, it would seem that dhcpcd is remembering that the address originally came from a different DHCP server and thus will not accept it.

Comment: "I've tried manually releasing the eth0 lease" please add how